# How do i put google analytics code into a Global field?

Tags: analytics

can anyone tell me step by step what to do to put google analytics code into a global field? I have read the earlier answer but i am new to craft and i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 5):

You should just be able to put it in a text field and then output it in an [`includeJs`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/includejs) statement. So, add a new global set (called 'googleAnalytics' or whatever); create a text field (called 'text' or whatever); and add the new field to your global set field layout.

In your template you should be able to access it by the globalSet handle.

```
{% includeJs googleAnalytics.text %}
```

Not tested, but I don't see any reason it shouldn't work. If the [`includeJs`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/includejs) statement doesn't like that for some reason you can try the following instead.

```
{% set GACode %}
    {{ googleAnalytics.text }}
{% endset %}
{% includeJs GACode %}
```

Comment: I tried this. What should be the correct field type for the text? I tried both Plain text and Rich Text. Both don't seem to work.

Comment: I would suggest plaintext. You may also need to use `raw` filter, so that it is not HTML encoded (i.e. `{{ googleAnalytics.text|raw }}`)